# boost aiso icmp socket: is having async_receive_from got called repeatedly sufficient?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

when reading the official boost icmp aync example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/icmp/ping.cpp:

```c
 void start_receive()
    {
        // Discard any data already in the buffer.
        reply_buffer_.consume(reply_buffer_.size());

        // Wait for a reply. We prepare the buffer to receive up to 64KB.
        socket_.async_receive(reply_buffer_.prepare(65536),
                              boost::bind(&pinger::handle_receive, this, _2));
    }
 void handle_receive(std::size_t length)
    {
        // The actual number of bytes received is committed to the buffer so that we
        // can extract it using a std::istream object.
        reply_buffer_.commit(length);

        // Decode the reply packet.
        std::istream is(&reply_buffer_);
        ipv4_header ipv4_hdr;
        icmp_header icmp_hdr;
        is >> ipv4_hdr >> icmp_hdr;

        // We can receive all ICMP packets received by the host, so we need to
        // filter out only the echo replies that match the our identifier and
        // expected sequence number.
        if (is && icmp_hdr.type() == icmp_header::echo_reply && icmp_hdr.identifier() == get_identifier() && icmp_hdr.sequence_number() == sequence_number_)
        {
            // If this is the first reply, interrupt the five second timeout.
            if (num_replies_++ == 0)
                timer_.cancel();

            // Print out some information about the reply packet.
            chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
            chrono::steady_clock::duration elapsed = now - time_sent_;
            std::cout << length - ipv4_hdr.header_length()
                      << " bytes from " << ipv4_hdr.source_address()
                      << ": icmp_seq=" << icmp_hdr.sequence_number()
                      << ", ttl=" << ipv4_hdr.time_to_live()
                      << ", time="
                      << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count()
                      << std::endl;
        }
        start_receive();
    }
```

I've got some questions:

- what if in `handle_receive`,I do some time-consuming work, say, acquire some lock just before the `start_recieve` got called again, will the demo example miss some icmp packets? I have this question because after some experiments, I found `handle_receive` got called only once instead of repeatedly after async handler registered, so you have to register the handler everytime `handle_receive` got fired
- what can i do to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

> what if in handle_receive,I do some time-consuming work, [...], will the demo example miss some icmp packets?

Yes. It will add latency. If the latency exceeds 5s, the request will be timed out.

> say, acquire some lock just before the start_recieve got called again

That's a problem. The lock will not guard any async operations anyways. You have a flaw in your logic there. It's hard to tell without seeing the code or knowing what you'd use the lock for.

> what can i do to avoid this situation?

Instead of locking, use a strand.

Instead of doing time-consuming work in a completion handler, do it on a different thread.